# Sum of first $n$ triangular numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would someone have arrived to the formula: 
$$s=\frac16 n^2+ \frac12 n^2+\frac13 n+d$$
I have tried induction but there is another method I am not seeing when solving, I know the function is the same as for square numbers but I am unable to make the connection.

Comment: What is $n$ and $d$?

Comment: Where does your formula for s come from? Are you trying to calculate the sum of the first n triangular numbers? So the first term is $\frac{1}{6}n^3$ and $d=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $n$-th triangle number is $T_n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$.

The sum of the first $n$-th triangle numbers:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n T_k
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n \dfrac{k(k+1)}2 \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n \left( \dfrac12k^2 + \dfrac12k \right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac12 \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k^2 + \dfrac12 \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac12 \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + \dfrac12 \dfrac{n(n+1)}2 \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{n(n+1)}{12}\left((2n+1)+3\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(n+2\right) \\
\end{array}$$

I believe you can expand it by yourself now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalization.

From the binomial coefficient identity
$\binom{n}{k}
=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}
$
we get
$\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k}
=\binom{n-1}{k-1}
$
or
$\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1}
=\binom{n}{k}
$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{n}{k}
&=\sum_{n=0}^m (\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1})\\
&=\binom{m+1}{k+1}-\binom{0}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{m+1}{k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Yours is the case
$k=2$
since the $n$-th triangular number
$T_n
=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
=\binom{n+1}{2}
$
so the sum is
$\binom{n+2}{3}
=\dfrac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{6}
$.

Comment: Yes, that's a classic!